# Jquery Auto trigger click after x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an auto click on my website in specific link but it doesnt work..
Also i am using a code if html doesn't load jquery to load and then run my script..

My code doesn't click... any ideas?

```
<div id="mydiv">
<a id="aww" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">ss</a>
</div>

<script>
(function() {
    // Load the script
    var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    // Poll for jQuery to come into existance
    var checkReady = function(callback) {
        if (window.jQuery) {
            callback(jQuery);
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(function() { checkReady(callback); }, 100);
        }
    };

// Start polling...
checkReady(function($) {

$(document).ready(function(){ 
setTimeout(function() {
$('#aww').trigger('click'); 
}, 9000);
});


    });
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply in pure JS?

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
    var href = document.getElementById('aww').getAttribute('href'); 
    window.location.href = href;
},2000);
</script>

</body>
```